# How to migrate Ubuntu to a new SSD

Tags: ubuntu, clone, gparted, migration

I'm trying to move my Ubuntu installation to a new SSD but all the guides that I found are either incomplete or the partition layout is different than mine.

[image]

I would use Ubuntu live and clone the sdd5 partition with gparted to the new ssd. What else do I need to do?

The sdd2 partition has boot and esp flag. Do I clone that as well? Do I need to install grub on one of the partitions and how do I do that? Do I need to change fstab and some UUIDs?

Or should I use some all in one cloning software instead of gparted?

Comment: I always suggest new install and restore from your backup. Tests that backup has everything you need when hard drive fails to restore to new drive while you still have old install to get anything missing. Also you are using the very old MBR partitioning with UEFI? UEFI should be using gpt partitioning. Microsoft has required UEFI/gpt since 2012. Ubuntu does let you use MBR, but probably should not. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: this is Ubuntu 21.04 installed few months ago with default settings following the installer, I just want to move it to a larger drive

Comment: Have you customized it? I would still create backups as you need to know how to do that. And then correctly install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drive. Backup at minimum should include /home & list of installed apps. If you edit system settings in /etc, you want to include those. I only edit a few files like grub, so just copy those into /home. If server install or server apps, add'l folders in / also required. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Comment: Why would I back up the drive? I want to clone it. Preferably properly on the first attempt. If that won't work then I would clone it in some other way. In the worst case I end up with the old drive the way it is now.

Comment: I don't understand why @oldfred thinks that the partition table is MBR. We don't see the Partition Table information on the screenshot and also, the esp flag on the boot partition indicates that it is a GPT partition table, and not MBR. Am I missing something?

Comment: Only MBR(msdos) has extended partition as container for logical partitions. Gpt has only primary partitions. Ubuntu now seems to always add an ESP whether UEFI or BIOS install. And really should not install in UEFI boot mode to very, very old (circa 1980) MBR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using clonezilla. disk to disk clone with default options. Then on the new drive I just resized the partitions to take up all the unallocated space.

https://www.tecmint.com/linux-centos-ubuntu-disk-cloning-backup-using-clonezilla/